# How to install GNU grep on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, grep, homebrew

I need to install GNU grep on my Mac but I'm finding some difficulties.

I tried doing this:

```
brew install grep --with-default-names
```

But this is no longer an option since Homebrew removed `--with-default-names`.

Can anyone provide a solution for this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, `--with-default-names` was [removed](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/35720).

But some formulas, like `grep`, provided a workaround for this:

```
$ brew info grep
...
==> Caveats
All commands have been installed with the prefix "g".
If you need to use these commands with their normal names, you
can add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH from your bashrc like:
  PATH="/usr/local/opt/grep/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
...
```

First, to install, just do `install` without `--with-default-names`.

```sh
$ brew install grep
...
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/grep/3.3: 21 files, 880.7KB
```

You should also see that same "Caveats" info I mentioned at the start. Now, by default, the Homebrew `grep` would be prefixed by a "g", so it's accessible as `ggrep`.

```
$ ggrep -V
ggrep (GNU grep) 3.3
Packaged by Homebrew
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...
```

This prevents it from shadowing the built-in `grep` that comes with Mac.

```
$ grep -V
grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD
```

If you *really* need to use `grep` and not `ggrep`, just follow the instructions and put */usr/local/opt/grep/libexec/gnubin* at the start of your `PATH`. You have to do this in your *.bashrc* or *.bash_profile* (whichever one you use).

```sh
$ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/grep/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ source ~/.bash_profile
$ grep -V
grep: warning: GREP_OPTIONS is deprecated; please use an alias or script
grep (GNU grep) 3.3
Packaged by Homebrew
...
```